# “Next to” is to horizontal as what is to vertical?

Tags: prepositions

The thing I like about *next to* is that it does not specify whether it is to the left or to the right.

However, for the vertical *next to*, it appears one needs to specify whether it is “above” or “below”. I find quite interesting why this would be the case (cf. various other vertical versus horizontal biases: reading direction, attentional acuity, etc), but I also find it quite annoying.

I would like to find a word that is the equivalent of *next to* but which applies to the vertical case. That is, it indicates that a position is **either** above **or** below, without specifying which of those two applies.

Sample Sentences, assuming the preposition is *abaqine*:

> "The sparrow abaqine that falcon is casting a shadow on that sand
>   dune."
>
> "Look at those macaques, they're all climbing abaqine one another."
>
> "In my fridge all the good food is abaqine each other, so I can't get
>   it without toppling it all over."

Comment: Like *adjacent, next to* applies vertically as well as horizontally.

Comment: Okay. Are there two words that are equivalent to "vertically adjacent" and "horizontally adjacent" respectively?

Comment: I agree _next to_ vertically sounds wrong. _On top of_ and _below_ would be my choices for next to vertically. It is in my mind more important to know if something is above or below than if something is left or right to a thing

Comment: @CrisStringfellow: "Next to" would be an alternative to "horizontally adjacent".

Comment: @mplungjan: The OP wants a word that implies "on top of" as well as "below".

Comment: I realised that and amended my comment

Comment: @mplungjan yes I concur. More important. *Below top of*?

Comment: I don't think this is good enough to put as an answer, but the most concise I could come up with is "stacked together" but that's probably no better than "vertically adjacent", and perhaps less precise.

Comment: Stacked is actually pretty good. I think we are getting closer. Theere must be some ancient word that means this. There were *always* ancient words for everything.

Comment: 'Above', 'below'?

Answer (score 2):

- **proximate**
- **proximal**
- **adjacent**
- **nearest**
- **contiguous** (possibly)**

These are all synonyms for the concept of "next".   I would suggest having a sample sentence with which to test each word for reasonableness.

Comment: The first two could work in any n-dimensions (*it seems*). Nearest is unexpectedly good. Contiguous? I don't know. Ok, good idea with sample sentences. I'll edit within the next 12 hours.

Comment: Added sample sentences.

Answer (score 1):

I think @TecBrat is on the right track in the comments. Vertically adjacent items could be **stacked**, **layered**, or **piled** together. I'm still trying to come up with a good preposition, though.

Comment: Added sample sentences. I kept thinking of 'stacked' it's quite good.